# Trying to create a 'trending words/phrases' engine but need to filter out common words

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to parse strings coming into my system and keep a word count of each word in a separate table. Problem is many common words like 'the', 'at', etc will be included that shouldn't be. I would prefer not to create a dictionary by hand. Anyone know of a decent dictionary of common words I can match against to not include? Thanks.

Comment: This might be a good start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifically referring to a "Stop words" list.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words

You can find one here

http://truereader.com/manuals/onix/stopwords1.html